# UWP: Disabling Tooltips for MediaTransportControls - Element

Tags: windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to simply disable the tooltips for `<MediaTransportControls>` elements. However, the tooltip still shows as can be seen in this screenshot.

Using `<ToolTipService>` has no effect whatsoever on the Tooltip shown. The tooltips show for all elements in the MediaTransportControl as is shown in this screenshot of `ToolTip`:

[image]

Comment: I am afraid there is no simple fix like setting a property to “off”, you have to edit the template of the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, `ToolTipService` does not provide this method to disable `ToolTip`. For your requirement, you could use [`SetToolTip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.tooltipservice.settooltip#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ToolTipService_SetToolTip_Windows_UI_Xaml_DependencyObject_System_Object_) method to set all elements tooltip as `null` in the `MediaTransportControls`. And you could use `VisualTreeHelper` to find all child element. And I also create a `MediaTransportControlsExtension` class that you could use directly.

```
public static class MediaTransportControlsExtension
{
    public static void DisableTootip(this DependencyObject control)
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
            ToolTipService.SetToolTip(child, null);

            DisableTootip(child);
        }         
    } 
}
```

**Usage**

Please note, you need invoke this method after all element initialized.

```
private void MainMPE_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainMPE.TransportControls.DisableTootip();
}
```